# Is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}$ valid for real $n$?

Tags: calculus, limits

We have a standard result
$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1} \text{ for } n\in\mathbb Q.$$

The proof of this result is easy: This is obviously true for $n=0$. First we prove it for positive integers by factorisation and then we extend it for negative integers and then for rationals.

But I am not sure whether the result holds for *real* $n$. If, yes, then what is the proof? If I am not wrong, equivalently, I am asking for a proof of
$$
\frac{d}{dx}x^n = nx^{n-1}
$$
for real $n$, if it is valid. Though I am not sure whether it is valid for real $n$, indeed it is true for rational $n$.

Comment: For $\alpha$ real you will need to begin by asking: what is the **definition** of $x^\alpha$ for $\alpha$ real? The usual definition is $x^\alpha= \exp(\alpha \log x)$. Now you can differentiate $x^\alpha$ using chain rule and the derivatives of the $\exp$ and $\log$ functions.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2999527/limits-calculating-lim-limits-x-to-1-fracxa-1x-1-where-a-gt-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @jjagmath So, are you suggesting that the limit can be proved by L'Hopital's rule once we settle with the derivative of $x^n$?

Comment: @prashantsharma, why would you use L'Hospital to find derivative of $\exp(\alpha\log x)$?

Comment: @Ennar Alright, you are saying the limit itself is the derivative of $x^n$?

Comment: You said it yourself, and you were correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$y=x^n,$$
for $n\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
&\ln(y) = n\ln(x)\\
\implies&\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=n\frac{1}{x}\\
\implies&\frac{dy}{dx} = n y \frac{1}{x} = n\frac{x^n}{x}= nx^{n-1}.
\end{align*}
$$

I think this proof is right.

Comment: You mean first we have to find the derivative and then the required limit?

Comment: No. The derivative of $y$ is exactly the derivative you want to find. Think abou $y$ as a function of $x$ such that $y(x) = x^n$.

Comment: My primary question is about finding the limit.

Comment: This limit is exactly the derivative. To find the limit is equivalent to find the derivative

Answer (score 0):

How about this.
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal L &=& \lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=\\
&=&\lim_{x\to a}\frac{[a+(x-a)]^n-a^n}{x-a}=\\
&=&\lim_{x\to a}a^{n-1}\frac{\left[1+\left(\frac{x}{a}-1\right)\right]^n-1}{\frac{x}{a}-1}{=}na^{n-1}
\end{eqnarray}$$
where, in the last step, I used the fundamental limit
$$\frac{(1+\alpha(x))^k-1}{\alpha(x)} \to k,$$
when $\alpha(x) \to 0$, for any real $k$.

Comment: Can you please suggest the proof of 'fundamental limit' for real $k$?

Comment: @prashantsharma The standard approach is to refer to the other fundamental limit by replacing $(1+\alpha(x))^k$ with $e^{k\log(1+\alpha(x))}$.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain? Otherwise it is useless to do so. Do you feel the need for futher clarifications?

Comment: In essence, you are suggesting the same thing what jjagmath said, right?

Comment: @prashantsharma oh, yes! Didn't notice the comment, but the essence is the same.

Comment: @prashantsharma I wouldn't say, though, you **need** $e$ to define $x^r$, with $r$ real. The appearance of $e$ is actually due to the limit and to the question: where does $(1+x)^{\frac1x}$ converge to, when $x\to 0$? And to this main question, all others sooner or later refer to.